# Regularization for unordered vectors

Tags: optimization, order-theory, regularization

Let suppose we have two vectors **u**, **v** $\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and we want a function that returns $0$ if the ordering of the elements of both vectors are the same or a positive number otherwise, where the larger the number of order mismatches the larger the positive value. We want that the highest values of the vector **u** place in the same positions of the highest values in vector **v**.

For example: Lets say that **u** = {3.2, 1.5, -3, 0} and **v**={-2.1, 1, 1.1, -0.5}, so the rank of these vectors are (descending order): $r_u$={1,2,4,3} and $r_v$={4,2,1,3}. So, in this case we have two matches {2,3} and two mismatches {1,4}. Another point is that the highest value of the vectors **u** and **v** is in the mismatch set, then in this case the penalization should be harder than a mismatch in lower values.

The simplest way to do that is by calculating the rank of each vector, $r_u$ and $r_v$, and then compute the $L_2$-norm, for example, of the difference between these ranks:

$f(r_u,r_v) = \|r_u-r_v\|^2_2$.

However, since this function is a term of my optimization problem, at each iteration of the optimization algorithm it will be necessary to recalculate the ranks of these vectors, once both vectors are parameters to be learned and they are going to change every iteration. So, this approach can be very expensive, computationally speaking.

Another option is by counting the number of concordant pairs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordant_pair) of the vectors, however we 
need to recount the number of concordant (or discordant) pairs at each iteration.

Does anybody has faced with a similar problem?

Comment: If I understand you right, your function is a metric in some optimization algorithm. If you really think, order-theory could help here, you should add more information about the underlying algorithm that produces the vectors $\mathbb u$ and $\mathbb v$. You could describe the order mismatch as a permutation. The penalty could be the the product of the cycles. An you could add an additional penalty if the highest value don't match. Again it's the algorithm itself that holds the key to your problem. If you don't disclose it, I'm afraid no one can really help you.

Comment: This is a spatial data analysis problem, where I have one regression problem for each geographical location. These vectors **u** and **v** are, in fact, the parameters of two nearby regression models and these vectors are optimized by a first-order optimization method. Since the covariates have interpretable meaning, I want to enforce that the most important covariates of nearby models are the same. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have they the same meaning? If yes maybe singualar value decomposition might help: Just consider $u$ und and $v$ as a $2×n$ matrix. If not it's probably better to use different methods as fuzzy concept analysis and their factor analysis methods.

Comment: Yes Keinstein, they have the same meaning. I'll think the regularization in terms of SVD decomposition and try to understand how it's related to the ordering of elements in **u** and **v**. Maybe it's not that efficient since I need to compute SVD decompositions at each optimization algorithm iteration. I have came up with a LP formulation for this problem, I believe it is going to work. If so, I'll put the formulation here.